# Bitbucket Pull request без fork-a репозитория

Tags: bitbucket, git

Есть репозиторий на битбакет. Нужно, чтобы другой человек, у которого есть только права на чтение, смог создать ветку, сделать в ней что-то и прислать pull request. Возможно ли это? Возможно ли это без Fork-а репозитория?

**Обновление**

В идеале локатьно комитил, а потом создавал пул реквест, который будет виден на битбакет без веток и форков. Понимаю, что тупой вопрос, но реально ли так? Или чтобы сам создал ветку лоально, а потом пулреквестом ее добавить.

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Внесенные изменения должны где-то храниться. Если не в форке, то где? Вариант [[@0xFFh](/users/10774/0xffh)](/users/10774/0xffh) достаточно хорош.

А почему хотите обойтись без форков? Просто не совсем понятно: с одной стороны, у человека нету прав на изменение исходного репозитория, с другой стороны, не хочется форков. Какая-то странная ситуация. Как же он работать-то будет с кодом?

Answer (score 1):

Можно вручную создать ветку и выставить ей соответствующие разрешения для операций pull/push.

Answer (score 1):

Можно [ограничить права](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-branch-permissions-776639807.html) на изменения конкретной ветки репозитория (скорее всего master). При этом другим сотрудникам дать права на запись ко всем остальным веткам. Сотрудники смогу хранить код в основном репозитории, не создавая форков, но не смогут изменять основную ветку.